# Locking Variables when Threading in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, queue

I have a C# program, where I'm spawning a thread to do some calculations. I'm then adding the result of the calculations to a Queue, and from the main thread, I'm constantly checking to see if the Queue has length more than 0. If it does, then the result of the calculation is de-queued and used elsewhere.

I've read that I should lock the queue when accessing it from either thread because it may cause problems if both threads are accessing it at the same time. But should I lock it whenever I do ANYTHING with the Queue, or only when en-queuing/de-queuing?

E.g.

```
// In main thread

lock (meshDataQueue) {
  if (meshDataQueue.Count > 0)
  {
    constructMesh(meshDataQueue.dequeue())
  }
}
```

vs.

```
if (meshDataQueue.Count > 0) {
  lock (meshDataQueue)
  {
    constructMesh(meshDataQueue.dequeue())
  }
}
```

Comment: Since the queue is changed within the thread, you should lock it before you check the count.

Comment: Why not use ConcurrentQueue?

Comment: @Charlieface I wasn't aware of that datastructure. Thank you.

Comment: @ShreyJoshi - You should always `lock` for any access to a `Queue`, but you should get in the habit of not locking on the instance of the `Queue` - always create a single new object that has as limited scope as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should lock the `Queue` instance (using always the same "locker" object) whenever you do anything with it, including trivial things like reading the queue's `Count`. The `Queue` class is not thread-safe, so for its behavior to stay defined you must ensure that it is accessed by one thread at a time (with proper memory barriers when switching from thread to thread, that the `lock` statement robustly provides). Otherwise you enter the undefined behavior territory, where all guarantees are off.